# Error parsing JSON returned via Symfony Component's JsonResponse

Tags: php, json, symfony, jsonresponse, symfony-http-foundation

My Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url : path,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType : 'json',
    data: data,
    success: function(memberExtra) {
        console.log (memberExtra);
    }
});
```

My response:

```
HTTP/1.0 201 Created
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type:  application/json
Date:          Tue, 10 Feb 2015 23:49:09 GMT

{"memberExtras":{"label":"seller","dropdown":"abc"}}
```

My PHP:

```
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;

/**
 * Update the pulldown menus.
 *
 * @Route("/classification", name="classification")
 * @Template()
 */
public function classificationAction(Request $request)
{
    $memberType = $request->request->get('classification');

    $label = $memberType["user"]["memberType"];
    $dropdown = "abc";
    $response = new Response(json_encode(array('memberExtras' => array(
        'label' => $label,
        'dropdown' => $dropdown,
    ))), Response::HTTP_CREATED);
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    return new Response($response);
}
```

The **console.log** doesn't output anything. Even if a regular text expression like **("test")**.

If I remove the **dataType : 'json'** declaration and attempt to manually parse the data via **$.parseJSON(memberExtra)**, I get this error:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

Not too surprised. Basically, it seems that the parser gets tripped on the header returned by the Symfony class. How can I avoid this header and just get to the JSON?

Thanks!

Comment: quick note, doesnt look like you're actually using `JsonResponse`...

Comment: try simply  `return  $response  `  instead of   `return new Response($response); `
BTW I suggest you to simply use  `return new JsonResponse($myarray)` and remove the annotation `@Template` from your method. Hope this help

Comment: @Matteo - That was it! Just looking at the code over and over and over again, I could not see such a silly mistake. Thank you for lending your eyes.

I will take your other suggestions into account as well. Very much appreciated!

Comment: nice! I will post as answer so you can close your question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try simply:

`return $response;`

instead of return

`new Response($response);`

BTW I suggest you to simply use

```
return new JsonResponse($myarray)
```

and remove the annotation @Template from your method.

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

Replace `return new Response($response);` with `return $response;`

Basic syntax:

```
$response = new Response();

$response->setContent(json_encode(array(
    'id' => $entity->getId(),
    'other' => $entity->getOther(),
)));

$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

return $response;
```